# Cocos2d iphone touch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

Is there a way to detect touch events from another class than the Layer itself. 
I'm trying to have a state controlling the interaction, adding listener to the layer itself if needed instead of have the layer call a function on the current state, which might be a noop.
Is the a way to use such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the class `CCTouchDispatcher` (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_touch_dispatcher.html)

You can subscribe any class that implements `CCStandardTouchDelegate` or `CCTargetedTouchDelegate` to receive touch events, by calling:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addStandardDelegate:self priority:1];
```

on your `onEnter` method (assuming your class is a `CCNode`), and then remove it from the dispatcher via:

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
```

at your `onExit` method.